# How to make an internal method call check

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How can I use Mockito to check a call inside a method to another method of another class?

```
public class FirstClass {
    private SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();
    public void sum() {
        secondClass.sum_2(1, 2);
    }
}
```

I need to check that the second **Class.sum_2()** method is called with parameters

MyTest:

```
public class FirstTest {

    FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass();
    SecondClass secondClass = Mockito.spy(SecondClass.class);

    @Test
    public void first() {
        firstClass.sum();
        Mockito.verify(secondClass).sum_2(eq(1), eq(2));
    }
}
```

But answer:
Wanted but not invoked:
*secondClass.sum_2(1, 2);
-> at FirstTest.first(FirstTest.java:14)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.*

Comment: The way you wrote that you can't. If ```FirstClass```is calling a method in ```SecondClass```as you shown, you can either create a static method (it seems not to be dependent on anything inside) and call it like this: ```StaticSecondClass.sum_2()```or you can, if the static way is not available, pass a SecondClass object when creating the FirstClass one.

Then test that is trivial. And the latest versions of Mockito supports mockStatic too.

Be more specific to be helped better.

Comment: You need to write `FirstClass` in such a way that `SecondClass` can be injected as dependency. Preferrably via constructor. Then you can create an instance of `FirstClass` with your spy.
Right now, the spy you create has no connection to the `secondClass` instance in your class under test.

Comment: If you can't normally pass it in the constructor, you can create a protected constructor just for tests which does take a `SecondClass` parameter. Not ideal but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities how to solve this problem. As I mentioned in my comment, the most common approach is to create a constructor in `FirstClass` with a `SecondClass` parameter, so that you can inject an instance from outside.

## Constructor injection

```
public class FirstClass {
    private SecondClass secondClass;

    public FirstClass(SecondClass secondClass) {
        this.secondClass = secondClass;
    }

    public void sum() {
        secondClass.sum_2(1, 2);
    }
}

public class FirstTest {

    FirstClass firstClass;
    SecondClass secondClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        secondClass = Mockito.spy(new SecondClass());
        firstClass = new FirstClass(secondClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void first() {
        firstClass.sum();
        Mockito.verify(secondClass).sum_2(eq(1), eq(2));
    }
}
```

If you can not create a constructor, you could add a setter and inject your instance that way.

## Setter injection

```
public class FirstClass {
    private SecondClass secondClass;

    public void setSecondClass(SecondClass secondClass) {
        this.secondClass = secondClass;
    }

    public void sum() {
        secondClass.sum_2(1, 2);
    }
}

public class FirstTest {

    FirstClass firstClass;
    SecondClass secondClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        secondClass = Mockito.spy(new SecondClass());
        firstClass = new FirstClass();
        firstClass.setSecondClass(secondClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void first() {
        firstClass.sum();
        Mockito.verify(secondClass).sum_2(eq(1), eq(2));
    }
}
```

And if you really, *really* can't modify `FirstClass` at all, you have to resort to using reflection.

## With reflection

```
public class FirstClass {
    private SecondClass secondClass;

    public void sum() {
        secondClass.sum_2(1, 2);
    }
}

public class FirstTest {

    FirstClass firstClass;
    SecondClass secondClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        secondClass = Mockito.spy(new SecondClass());
        firstClass = new FirstClass();
        Field field = FirstClass.class.getDeclaredField("secondClass");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(firstClass, secondClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void first() {
        firstClass.sum();
        Mockito.verify(secondClass).sum_2(eq(1), eq(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The option with reflection suits me.
Good luck and have a nice day!